# How to build all configurations with CMake + msbuild

Tags: cmake, msbuild

I have a CMake file that generates VS2015 solution file MyApp.sln. I build MyApp.sln with the following commands separately for each configuration:

```
msbuild MyApp.sln /property:Configuration=Debug
msbuild MyApp.sln /property:Configuration=RelWithDebInfo
msbuild MyApp.sln /property:Configuration=Release
```

I wonder if anyone knows how to build all the configurations with a single msbuild command. Probably CMake can generate some 'All' configuration, for example?

My question is a bit different from [How can I build all with MSBuild from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842706/how-can-i-build-all-with-msbuild-from-the-command-line), because I do not modify MyApp.sln file manually, but it is generated by CMake, so I need either some option in CMake to create 'all' target or call msbuild in a way it builds all the configurations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I build all with MSBuild from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842706/how-can-i-build-all-with-msbuild-from-the-command-line)

Comment: probably my questions is a bit different, because I use CMake

Comment: CMake is used to generate a solution, but you build it using msbuild.

Comment: Did you already tried `msbuild MyApp.sln /t:ALL_BUILD /Configuration:"Debug;Release;RelWithDebInfo"`?

Comment: With the command msbuild LinesGameQt.sln /t:ALL_BUILD /p:Configuration="Debug;Release;RelWithDebInfo" I get 'error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Debug;Release;RelW
ithDebInfo|Win32" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (
e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU")'

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit silly, but you can add a custom target to CMake that causes the project build itself:

```
add_custom_target(build_all_configs
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target ALL_BUILD --config Debug
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target ALL_BUILD --config Release
)
```

You get the idea... Note that [CMake can build its own projects](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/manual/cmake.1.html#build-tool-mode), so there is no need to resort to MSBuild at all.

While this works fine, I would rather [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/configure_file.html) a batch script that does the same thing to a location that works for your needs. That will definitely raise fewer eyebrows than the custom command above.