# How can I build all configurations with MSBuild VS2015 from the command line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

In previous versions of MSBUILD you can build all configurations in a solution using the following command line arguments:

```
msbuild /t:BuildAll /Configuration:"Debug;Release;ContinuousIntegration"
```

as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842706/how-can-i-build-all-with-msbuild-from-the-command-line)

However this does not work with MSBUILD VS2015 and gives the following error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.
Switch: Release
```

This is a similar question to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051699/how-to-build-all-configurations-with-cmake-msbuild) however I am not using cmake just simply straight MSBUILD

Comment: That linked question/anser is, as far as I can see, about writing a custom target called BuildAll and having it build all other projects using all condifgurations. As such not much changed: you'd still have to write the BuildAll target yourself, and let it iterate over configurations (which you can either hardcode or supply on the commandline). The principle basically is `<MsBuild Project="my.sln" Properties="Configuration=%(AllMyConfigs.Identity)"/>`, this has definitely been asked/answered here before.

Comment: @stijn you are right, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this directly through command line options in MSBUILD and I have achieved the same effect as my linked post. I'm not sure whether just to close this answer or post the "You cant do this directly" result as an answer, thoughts?

Comment: I looked around a bit and searching for queries like 'msbuild multiple configurations' turns up usable answers so slosing seems ok, but it's up to you of course. You could also close by linking to an (almost) duplicate like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511274/using-msbuild-to-build-multiple-configurations or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984882/how-can-i-build-multiple-configurations-in-parallel or possibly others

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I build all with MSBuild from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842706/how-can-i-build-all-with-msbuild-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score -2):

For example:

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"Uninstaller.vcxproj /property:Configuration=Release'
```

Sometimes you need run this for setting environment

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat"'
```